# Configure Enzyme Test with material UI Theme Provider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

Hi everyone I have a problem current I use material ui in my app with react, but I need to wrap each component with ThemeProvider in test to get theme throught props

```
 const wrapperFilter = mount(
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={createTheme(defaultTheme)}>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={createGenerateClassName()}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
          <SortFilter {...props} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StylesProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
```

but I think that is not the correct way, I tried to inject via setupTest.js but I only have option to set default theme

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { ThemeConsumer } from "styled-components";
import { defaultTheme } from './@next/globalStyles';


// set default theme for enzyme renderer
ThemeConsumer._currentValue = defaultTheme;
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using React 18, MUI v5 and enzyme for my tests.
I encountered the same issue, what I have done is:

1. Create a file that will wrap my component in my tests injecting the theme and using shallow from enzyme:

```
// enzymeThemeWrapper.js

import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import theme from 'resources/myTheme';

import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

export const shallowMUITheme = component =>
  shallow(
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{component}</ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>,
  );
```

2. then use it like so in my tests:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallowMUITheme } from 'utils/enzymeThemeWrapper';
import Screen from '../screen';

describe('screen', () => {
  it('should render screen', () => {
    const component = shallowMUITheme(
      <Screen />,
    );

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

You probably figured this out since then, I would be curious to know what solution you came up with to solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

HI sorry for the late answer this happend many years ago, but I remember that I use similar solution as you comment wrap my component